# What is this tool's name/use?

Tags: hand-tools

My uncle left me this tool.  Looks like a tire chain tightener or something you'd hook and stretch.  Anyone know the name of this tool?

[image: tool with flat bar s-hook on the business end]

Comment: What type of work was your uncle known to undertake?

Comment: It looks like a bar that I use to lift motors so I can add shims. But this would only be if the tip was some what flat

Comment: Looks like a lever: place the curved arm through (wire loop or end of spring) then put the curved inside of the hook onto the (pin or lever) where it's supposed to. Then pull the handle until whatever #1 is pulled "over the top" and engages on whatever #2.

Comment: looks like a german tickler. /s

Comment: maybe a spring hook for removing and installing springs

Comment: Can we get a pic from a different angle to see what that piece nearer the handle is?

Comment: It looks rather like a Xtra-Large version of my dental hygienists's tools.  Maybe this is for cleaning large animals'  teeth.   [no not really]

Comment: I think I saw that used at the end of 'Braveheart'.

Answer (score 7):

It's called a Snap-Up lever. It's used to secure weight distribution hardware from a vehicle to a tow-behind trailer, RV, etc. Video of it in use here: https://youtu.be/FYFYcqxlJzc?t=334